# Сумму А+В=С ограничить значениями от 0 до 6

Tags: excel, excel-формулы

Подскажите, возможно ли реализовать такую формулу в одной ячейке, что то типа такого:

```
=SUM(K4;L4;IF(J22>6;J22-6))
```

Нужно, чтобы сумма двух ячеек оставалась простым числом:

- если сумма от 0 до 6 (включительно), то сумму не менять;
- если сумма >6 и <=12, то от ответа отнять 6;
- если сумма >12 и <=18, то -12;
- если сумма >18 и <=24, то -18;

и т.д....

Если возможно, помогите правильно оформить. Или придется ответ "если" выносить в отдельную ячейку?

Comment: так вы не Если в сумму запихивайте, а наоборот, будет у у вас две суммы внутри если. Одна в условии, вторая в выражении

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что вы складываете число из ячейки j22 - но только от 0 до 5, если больше 6 то -6, если больше 12 -12 и т.д.? тогда вам можно вычислять остаток от деления на 6 `ОСТАТ(J22;6)` и функция будет `=СУММ(K4;L4;ОСТАТ(J22;6))` а если вся сумма не должна быть больше 6 то `=ОСТАТ(СУММ(K4;L4);6)`

Comment: Мы складываем числа любые. Из 2 ячеек там может быть 1+1, 3+2, 8+5 и тд. Если то что будет ответом 1,2,3,4,5,6 мы так и оставляем, а если больше 6(например 7,8,9,10,11,12) то нужно чтобы формула считала 7......12-6=. Если больше 12(13,14,15,16,17,18) то например 16-12=4. Если 19,20,21,22,23,24 = число -18. И до 31...36-30=

Comment: Ну скорее всего да от 0, только до 6 включительно. Чтоб любая из сумм была не выше 6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=ОСТАТ(A2+B2-1;6)+1
```

Суммируйте хоть десятки тысяч - результат всегда будет от 1 до 6. Можно обернуть в проверку на нулевую сумму:

```
=ЕСЛИ(A2+B2;ОСТАТ(A2+B2-1;6)+1;)
```

Comment: Если возможны отрицательные или дробные значения, формулу нужно подправить (доработать)

Comment: Отрицательных не будет

Answer (score 1):

Здравстуйте @Artur
Вместо A1 и B1 вставьте свои ячейки.

Если Excel английский, замените функции на: ЕСЛИМН - IFS, ЕСЛИ - IF, И - AND, СУММ - SUM

Для Excel начиная от 2016:

```
=ЕСЛИМН(И(СУММ(A1;B1)>=6;СУММ(A1;B1)<=12);СУММ(A1;B1)-6;И(СУММ(A1;B1)>12;СУММ(A1;B1)<=18);СУММ(A1;B1)-12;И(СУММ(A1;B1)>18;СУММ(A1;B1)<=24);СУММ(A1;B1)-18)
```

Для старых Excel:

```
=ЕСЛИ(И(СУММ(A1;B1)>=6;СУММ(A1;B1)<=12);СУММ(A1;B1)-6;ЕСЛИ(И(СУММ(A1;B1)>12;СУММ(A1;B1)<=18);СУММ(A1;B1)-12;ЕСЛИ(И(СУММ(A1;B1)>18;СУММ(A1;B1)<=24);СУММ(A1;B1)-18)))
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь. После ввода формулы Error пишет. А скобок там больше не нужно?

Comment: Хмм... @Artur, возможно у вас оффис 2013? (ЕСЛИМН) появился только в версии 2016. Тогда нужно городить вложенные (ЕСЛИ)

Comment: @Artur, вот со вложенными множественными (ЕСЛИ) - добавил в ответ